# calling one form from another when button is click

Tags: vb.net

I am having two forms in vb where main form contains button and on button click event form2 will load.

I wrote this code:

```
Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles newCustomer.Click
    Dim d As BlankPage1 = New BlankPage1
    d.show()
End Sub
```

where Blankpage1 is the name of second form. The problem is after clicking button, Blankpage1 doesn't appear.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?  Do you have any code that **closes** BlankPage1 automatically?...

Answer (score 0):

Try `BlankPage1.show()` only, don't initialize first.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles newCustomer.Click
   form2.show()     //name of the form
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
Dim d As New BlankPage1
d.MdiParent = Me 'or the main form's name(MDI Parent Form)
d.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
d.Show()
d.Focus()
```